# How to trigeer two function with one react component?

Tags: react-native

I create a class component with animation for common button:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Animated, Easing, View } from 'react-native';

class AnimatedPrimaryButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      toggle: false,
      animated: new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }

  animatedButton = (toggle) => {
    this.state.animated.setValue(toggle ? 1 : 0);

    Animated.timing(this.state.animated, {
      toValue: toggle ? 0 : 1,
      duration: 250,
      easing: Easing.bounce
    }).start();

    this.setState({ toggle: !toggle });
  }

  render() {
    const { toggle, animated } = this.state;
    const { onPress, disabled, width, height } = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        disabled={disabled} 
        onPress={onPress} 
        style={[styles.buttonStyle, { width, height }]}
      >
        <Animated.View style={{ 
            // other styles
            transform: [{ scale: animated.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [0, 1]})
              }
            ]
        }}>
        </Animated.View>
        <Text style={[styles.textStyle, { fontSize }]}>
          {children}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }; 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // some styles
});

export default AnimatedPrimaryButton;
```

I use the create component on other screen like:

```
import AnimatedPrimaryButton from '../Shared/Button/AnimatedPrimaryButton';

doSomething = () => {
  // do something...
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <AnimatedPrimaryButton
        onPress={() => this.doSomething()}
        width={400} 
        height={57} 
        fontSize={20} 
        backgroundColor={confirmButtonBg}
        disabled={disabledConfirmButton}
      >
        {I18n.t('SIGN_IN_BUTTON')}
      </AnimatedPrimaryButton>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Now I want to use `doSomething` function and trigger `animatedButton` at the same time.

In some conditions my `disable` will switch true or false, so I try to set the code on my AnimatedPrimaryButton is not working.

```
onPress={() => !disabled ? this.animatedButton(toggle) : onPress}
```

It looks like use the props `onPress` under arrow function won't work.

How to use `doSomething` and `animatedButton` function on class component `AnimatedPrimaryButton` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After animation completes call your `doSomething()`. You can achieve it by giving **delay** between two functions call

Comment: But my `doSomething()` and `animatedButton()` is separate, how to set dalay after animation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `AnimatedPrimaryButton` component you can make a onPress function

```
onPress(){
  this.props.onPress();
  this. animatedButton();
}
```

and rest you are sending the doSomething() function correctly on onPress while calling `AnimatedPrimaryButton` on other screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try it later.

Comment: Thanks you very much ! It is the solution.

Comment: happy to help! :) happy coding!